# Repo / key of Skype

Tags: apt, skype

I have 17.04 and today I installed Skype for Linux, but when I execute `sudo apt update` I get the following:

```
W: Errore GPG: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: Le seguenti firme non sono state verificate perché la chiave pubblica non è disponibile: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
E: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

(Translation of the first line: *GPG error The following signatures were not verified since public key is not available*)

How can I solve?

Comment: How  did you install skype?

Comment: @Ravexina Just as told in the official Skype website, with the .deb package (it's the latest version, 5.3.0.1)

I don't know how to use the man page, so I need a little help ;-)

Comment: @David Foerster No, I didn't meant to install Skype (Beta , by the way) via console. It just lacked the integration into the updating system of Ubuntu :). Damn M$!!! >:\

Comment: @JKandy-drew: One answer to the linked question explains how to install Sky Beta from the same repository *and* how to set it up correctly with the public key and all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that after installing skype using its `deb` installer, it will add skype's repositories into your sources file, after adding a repository to your sources, you should add its public key too, however it seems that Skype did not add its public key to your system so you should add it manually:

As [here](https://repo.skype.com/) states:

```
 curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

If you don't have `curl`:

```
wget -O - https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```